# Assembly rename and Xaml resources

Tags: c#, wpf, mono.cecil

I want to be able to load a dll into one app domain multiple times and it should be possible to make code changes between every load. Currently I use Mono.Cecil to rename the namespace on types to accomplish this. If the dll includes wpf resources it should also rename the namespace on the balm (compiled xaml) files. I haven’t found any example to accomplish this. Has anyone had this issue before and what’s the best way to solve this?

Comment: This doesn't sound sustainable, can you give more details about what you're trying to accomplish? Why don't you use a custom MarshalByRef object with a shared lib to marshall the calls across separate appdomain, and then you can unload the DLLs when you dispose the app domain?

Comment: I’m loading my dll’s in my add-in to another app called Autodesk Revit. Revit don’t allow me to create a app domain and I need to work with the objects in the Revit app domain. By renaming my dll’s and loading them multiple times is the only workaround I have found.